# How can I get the workflow definition of a logic app as JSON?

Tags: powershell, azure-logic-apps

How can I get the workflow definition of a logic app as JSON?

I can create a new Logic App from a JSON definition file using the [New-AzLogicApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/New-AzLogicApp) command

But I can't see how to reverse the process, i.e. get the JSON definition of an existing Logic App.

I've tried the [Get-AzLogicApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/Get-AzLogicApp) which returns a [Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.logic.models.workflow?view=azure-dotnet) object.

But I'm blocked on the last step, i.e. from the Workflow back to an actual JSON file

Comment: Sorry, work priorities blocking me ... I do have it on my to-do list

Comment: well, Actually it just needs one minute to test it.;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the definition of the logic app, try the command as below.

```
$logicapp = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/workflows -ResourceName "<logic app name>"
$logicapp.properties.definition | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

If you want to get it as a `.json` file, just change the second line as below.

```
$logicapp.properties.definition | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\logic.json"
```

**Update:**

You could specify the [`-Depth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6#parameters) parameter of  `ConvertTo-Json`  with `3`, if you want more levels of contained objects are included in the JSON representation, you can also specify it with other values.

> -Depth
>
> Specifies how many levels of contained objects are included in the JSON representation. The default value is 2.

```
$logicapp.properties.definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

[image]

Comment: Working, but not 100% ... the runAfter values are set to e.g. "runAfter": "@{Create_blob=System.Object[]}",

Comment: When it should be ... "runAfter": { "Create_blob": [ "Succeeded" ] },

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `REST API` to get the details.

REST Api [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/get)

Or can you try using the `Get-AzLogicApp | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json` and see if that helps

Comment: The second option fails with error ... ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Logic.Models.Workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I've drilled down for a project in a client u need to do this:

```
1 )Get-AzLogicApp 
$lapp.Definition.ToString()-> this is the entire definition of the logicapp
2) Save the definition to a file
3) Use New-AzLogicApp or Set-AzLogicApp with -DefinitionFilePath pointing to that file  

$a= New-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $rg -name $name1 -location $loc -DefinitionFilePath  $fileName1 -ParameterFilePath $parm1
$a.Parameters.Count


*for Parameters i use this content in a file
{
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "office365": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/SUBS-DEPLOY/resourceGroups/RG-DEPLOY/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                "connectionName": "office365",
                "id": "/subscriptions/SUBS-DEPLOY/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/office365"
            },
            "sharepointonline": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/SUBS-DEPLOY/resourceGroups/RG-DEPLOY/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sharepointonline",
                "connectionName": "sharepointonline",
                "id": "/subscriptions/SUBS-DEPLOY/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/sharepointonline"
            }
        }
    }
}
replace SUBS-DEPLOY with the subscription id and RG-DEPLOY with resource group name and all good.

Anything just buzz: stationsolutions_at_gmail.com

Hope it helps







Here's the code ..


function Get-LogicApp($resourceGroupName ,$location,$name)
{
    Write-Host " Get LogicApp Definition $name"
    $lapp = Get-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $name
    $o= $lapp.Definition.ToString()
    $fileName = "..\logicapps\" + $name + ".logicapp.json"
    $o | Out-File -FilePath $fileName
    $parms = "..\logicapps\templates\parms.json"
    $fileName = "..\logicapps\" + $name + ".logicapp.parms.json"
    Copy-Item -Path $parms  $fileName
    Write-Host " LogicApp Definition $resourceGroupName > $fileName"
}
```